# Get parameters from a popup box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, parameters, popup

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

```
public void execute(){
 RandomClass item = showPopupBox(randomClassArrayList).selectItem();
 randomClassArrayList.remove(item);//Obv I can make this one line.
}
```

`showPopupBox` would create a popup box (go figure), populate a list of radio buttons for each item on the list, and return a selected item from the list when you pushed the OK button. until then the execute method would wait for the popupbox to return the item from the popup box selected via radio button.

I cant really post anything more than this because if I could I wouldn't need to ask. I'm trying to fill a parameter via popup box.

My question is only related to having the `execute()` method wait for the OK button of the popup box to be pressed, which would fill the parameter and finish the `execute()` method

Comment: You could've at least cared to tell what gui technology you're talking about! Web / Swing / AWT / SWT / WHAT?

Comment: Would you mind googling your question before posting it? StackOverflow already contains this questoin multiple times!!!

Comment: adarshr I forgot to add the swing tag, why don't you calm down. besides, its not specified so really any answer that fits the question would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Adel Boutros Why don't you link me then. Why did you bother commenting if you didn't want to help. no answer, no link, no help. Yea thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this (not tested):

```
public static RandomClass showPopupBox(List<RandomClass> list)
{
    JRadioButton[] rdoArray = new JRadioButton[list.size()];
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JPanel rdoPanel = new JPanel();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        rdoArray[i] = new JRadioButton(list.get(i).toString());
        group.add(rdoArray[i]);
        rdoPanel.add(rdoArray[i]);
    }
    rdoArray[0].setSelected(true);

    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
    int option = pane.showOptionDialog(null, rdoPanel, "The Title",
                                       JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                       null, new Object[]{"Submit!"}, null);

    if(option == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            if(rdoArray[i].isSelected()) return list.get(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
RandomClass item = showPopupBox(randomClassArrayList);
```

Comment: So can you tell me what causes everything to wait. I've looked in the JOptionPane class especially at the ShowOptionDialog method and I don't see how the method delays its return until it receives input, which is pretty much exactly what I want.